# Joins from same table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join the same table "travel_plan" twice, as the value(s) I need are `location_from` & `location_to` in which I can then join the value to my cities table to grab the city name.

```
SELECT * FROM travel_plan 
LEFT JOIN Cities ON Cities.CityID = travel_plan.location_to AS plan_to 
LEFT JOIN Cities ON Cities.CityID = travel_plan.location_from AS plan_from
LEFT JOIN user_table ON travel_plan.user_id = user_table.id 
ORDER BY date_from DESC LIMIT 0,4") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Is it not joining correctly or is it `die`ing? Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS plan_to, LEFT JOIN Cities ON Cities.CityID = travel_plan.location_from AS pla' at line 1

Comment: LEFT JOIN cities [AS] cities1...LEFT JOIN cities [AS] cities2.. etc

Answer (score 2):

You need to use table aliases correctly when you're joining the same table more than once, as you're doing with `Cities` in this query.

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM travel_plan  AS tr
  LEFT JOIN Cities       AS C1     ON  C1.CityID = tr.location_to 
  LEFT JOIN Cities       AS C2     ON  C2.CityID = tr.location_from 
  LEFT JOIN user_table   AS us     ON tr.user_id = us.id 
   ORDER BY date_from DESC 
      LIMIT 0,4
```

The way you wrote your query, the LEFT JOIN AS clauses were misplaced and not used for qualifying the column names.

This use of `SELECT *` is really suboptimal, however. From this four-table JOIN, `SELECT *` kicks back lots of columns with duplicate names, which fouls up `_fetch_assoc()` methods in php.

Your best bet is to enumerate the columns you fetch, and provide aliases so they don't end up with the same names. I don't know the names of your columns so I have to guess, but it would go something like this.

```
SELECT us.name, us.id AS userid, 
       C1.cityname AS to_cityname,
       C2.cityname AS from_cityname,
  FROM ....
```

Then you'll find the values in $result['from_cityname'] after you fetch each row.

Comment: How would grab each of those values in PHP, would it be like $result['C1.City'] & $result['C2.City'] ??

Comment: thankyou, you taught me a fair bit there.. thankyou.

Answer (score -2):

You misuse the `AS` keyword, it can be only used in the select part of the query (before FROM), or optionally as alias for table references. But not in the `ON` part of a join. I guess what you want is:

```
SELECT *, c1.City as toCity, c2.City as fromCity  FROM travel_plan LEFT JOIN Cities c1 ON c1.CityID = travel_plan.location_to LEFT JOIN Cities c2 ON c2.CityID = travel_plan.location_from LEFT JOIN user_table ON travel_plan.user_id = user_table.id ORDER BY date_from DESC LIMIT 0,4
```

Now you can access the the column aliases `toCity` and `fromCity` in your resultset, even though the the original column names are the same.

Comment: As you can see in documentation's (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) table_factor -part, table names can be aliased. It is also a mandatory to make double-join on same table to work.

Comment: I did't say that table names cannot be aliased, I'm talking about the AS keyword, but thx for the -1

Comment: That's true. I misunderstood by reading your query before your reply.

Comment: How would grab each of those values in PHP, would it be like $result['plan_from.City'] & $result['plan_to.City'] ??

Comment: no, just use the table column name or a column alias. If you have more then one column called City, then you need column aliases. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Unknown column 'Cities.CityID' in 'on clause'

Comment: thankyou, you taught me a fair bit there.. thankyou.